# How to filter elements from array by checking with the key of element

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to filter month according to the number entered in the input field.

For example, if i enter '5' in the input field, it should filter 'May'.

My Array is :

```
items = [
    {0: 'Jan'},
    {1: 'Feb'},
    {2: 'Mar'},
    {3: 'Apr'},
    {4: 'May'},
    .
    .
    .
    {11: 'Dec}'
 ]
```

and i am trying by this way, but unable to solve the issue

```
 const inputText= '5';

 const filteredMonths = items.filter(item => {
        return (Object.keys(item).find(key =>
                item[key] && item[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(inputText))
    });
```

So, if i enter 5 , in filteredMonths, there should be 1 element "March".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use filter for this, you can do it by checking if the entry has a value for your key:

```
const inputText = '5';
const key = parseInt(inputText) - 1; // Because your key is a number and because you associated May with 4, not 5

const result = items.filter(item => item[key]); // returns [{4: 'may'}]
```

If you want the result to only contain the value, you can use map:

```
const result = items
        .filter(item => item[key]) // returns [{4: 'may'}]
        .map(item => item[key]); // returns ['may']
```

However, I don’t really understand why you aren’t using an array of strings instead:

```
const items = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec'];
const result = items[key]; // returns 'may'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this.

```
 const inputText= '5';
 const filteredMonths = items.filter(obj => (inputText - 1) in obj)
console.log(filteredMonths[0][inputText-1]) //May
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const items = [
  { 0: "Jan" },
  { 1: "Feb" },
  { 2: "Mar" },
  { 3: "Apr" },
  { 4: "May" }
];

const inputText = "2";

const filteredMonths = Object.values(items.find(
  obj => parseInt(inputText) - 1 in obj
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specifically need `filter` here. You can simply access the key  using the index:

```js
const month = items[parseInt(inputText)][parseInt(inputText)];
```

All you need to do is make sure the inputText is always a key that is present in the object, or else you get `undefined` result that you have to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the quick suggestions, but in my case , i was able to resolve the issue by using :

```
 const inputText = searchText.toString().toLowerCase();
 const filteredList = items.filter((item, key) => {
        return (key+1).toString().toLowerCase() === inputText
    });
```

I have used the filter index as key because anyhow, it was not properly getting the key of object as per iteration.